# Angularjs and Number.NaN

Tags: javascript, angularjs, null, undefined, nan

I was going through the angular docs when I ran into this:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/input.js#L1556

Notice that `this.$viewValue = Number.NaN;`

Not just in this doc but in other angular docs as well.

What is the advantage/disadvantage of doing it this way vs. just setting it as `undefined` or `null`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In AgularJS specific terms:**

> $viewValue
>
> Actual string value in the view.
>
> $modelValue
>
> The value in the model, that the control is bound to.

So, if you have an input, the value within it is in the form of a string. If you display model value or interpolated value as markup, `{{ myInt }}` or  `{{ 5 + 5 }}`, it will be displayed as string.

This is because HTML is a language of text, while JS is a language of functions and values. So, to handle this dual mode for double binding, AngularJS uses $viewValue service for the "display" value of a model field and uses the `$modelValue` to track the "actual" value.

The "display" value should never "undefined", because interpolation of an undefined model should not raise an error. and the "display" value should never be a number. So, before it is a formal string (interpolation of `$modelValue`), it is a `NaN`.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be that they use Nan because, according to [Section 4.3.23 of ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.23) NaN is defined as:

```
number value that is a IEEE 754 “Not-a-Number” value
```

So it's a number and not something undefined or null. The value is explained further in [Section 8.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.5)

Equality comparisons with NaN are defined in [Section 11.9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3):

```
The comparison x == y, where x and y are values, produces true or false. Such a comparison is performed as follows: If Type(x) is Number, then:

If x is NaN, return false.

If y is NaN, return false.
```

So For the purpose of comparison , isNaN() should be used instead:

```
isNaN(NaN)
// true
```